# Python regex get group position

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code:

```
a = '/afolder_l/location/folder_l/file.jpg'
p= re.compile("/.+/location/.+_([lr])/")
m = p.match(a)
```

Now,
print m.group(1) gives l, but I would like the position of the group as well.
Right now, m.span() gives a tuple with a position that includes all the text. How could I just get the location of l? Or 'r' since that's what I am trying to group?

Comment: I am not sure why it's not formatting properly. Typing this on my phone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to reference the *group number*:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> a = '/afolder_l/location/folder_l/file.jpg'
>>> p= re.compile("/.+/location/.+_([lr])/")
>>> m = p.match(a)
>>> m.span()
(0, 29)
>>> m.span(1)
(27, 28)
```

Comment: You might find it more reliable to use group names, if you intend to use m.group(i) to get the matched string, because m.group(i) can have strange behaviour that is not apparent when you get the string instead with m.groupdict()[groupname]. eg. use: re.compile("/.+/location/.+_(?P<f_letter>[lr])/"), and get with m.span('f_letter') and m.groupdict()['f_letter']

Comment: This is very tricky to find, maybe you could add a bit more explanation so Google can lead others here as well?

Answer (score 5):

You can use ***.span()*** method of ***SRE_Match object*** with integer argument input as a group number.

Some examples for more clarity. If you use 3 groups of ***()*** so the group ***0*** will be the full matched, and with argument input as integer number from 1 to 3 will be the matched and index of each group number with ***.group()*** and ***.span()*** method, respectively. Hope this helps!

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})")
>>> text = "2019/12/31"
>>> matched = regex.match(text)
>>> matched
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2019/12/31'>

>>> matched.groups()
('2019', '12', '31')
>>> matched.span()
(0, 10)

>>> matched.group(0)
'2019/12/31'
>>> matched.span(0)
(0, 10)

>>> matched.group(1)
'2019'
>>> matched.span(1)
(0, 4)

>>> matched.group(2)
'12'
>>> matched.span(2)
(5, 7)

>>> matched.group(3)
'31'
>>> matched.span(3)
(8, 10)
```